# Lisp Programming Error (Stack Overflow (deep))

Tags: recursion, lisp

I am to write a lisp program to produce the actual value of a hexadecimal number. I have written a function but seem to be getting a stackoverflow (deep) error. I was wondering if anyone could point out my mistake or guide me in the right direction.

I would appreciate it if no code was posted for this question as this is part of a homework assignment. Hence I would only like an explanation or direction where I might be going wrong.

I feel my problem is that my recursion is not terminating but I don't know how to fix it.

Here's my code:

```
(defun calc (hex)
  (if hex
    (if (> (length hex) 1)
     ( + (first (reverse hex)) (* 16 (calc (reverse hex)))) hex)))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, what is the type of input? Is it a number or a string or something else? And I assume the output is supposed to be the same number, but in base 10 correct?

Comment: The number is a list of type '(7 d d) sort of an exploded list of hex digits

Comment: And the output is supposed to be a base 10 number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "base case" (the case/state where recursion actually stops) is that `hex` has length of one or less. Tell me, each time you call `calc` again, is the input to `calc` ever getting smaller? if not, then it's mathematically impossible for the input to ever reach the base case.

Let's say `hex` starts with length 9. When you call `calc` again, you have reversed `hex`. So now `hex` is reversed, *but it still has a length of 9*. I suspect that is why the recursion never stops.

Comment: omg no its not thanks I think that's the problem. I meant to call (rest (reverse hex)) instead of just (reverse hex)

Comment: I had one last question. Would you happen to know how I might be able to convert an item like the character d into its decimal form 13 without using the parse-integer function? I read that lisp uses ~x but that doesn't seem to work for me for some reason.

Comment: Btw if anyone is wondering how I finally got over the hex representation problem,I was told to use the COND function which is the lisp equivalent of a switch-case in java. Pretty ugly and hard coded but it got the job done.